# Angular package for PDF Viewer that supports IE11?

Tags: angular, pdf, embed

Does anybody know a pdf viewer package for Angular that is compatible with IE11?
Any tips, links, tutorials will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options.

1. [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer)
2. [PrintJS](https://printjs.crabbly.com/)
3. `npm i ng2-pdf-viewer`
4. `npm i ngx-doc-viewer`

Comment: The 1st option specifically says "Limited Internet Explorer 11 support". The others provide even less insight into IE11 support, if any.

Comment: Have you tried pdf.js? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8192